# Ubuntu 14.04 32/64 bits no usb mouse keyboard no network waiting for network configuration

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb

i am used ubuntu and now i am reinstalled 14.04 64 and no mouse or keyboard or network i am use rescue console from install cd to gather this hw info

my network card is  qualcomm atheros AR8161 gigabyte cart

update:
well i am tryed to make new instalation cd and install 14.04 32 bit but same issues  during install  keyboard and mouse and net works

but final install doesnot

Comment: Have you checked the md5sum of your Ubuntu ISO before installing it? (Or select "Verify integrity of the medium" at the CD's menu). I experienced atheros devices to work quite well with Linux...

Comment: integrity checked

Comment: it is  any package at repo to enable my ethernet card

Comment: btw i did instalation via ubuntu 14.04 mini cd and network works during  install

Comment: How does the network card relate to the keyboard and mouse?

Comment: And how did you get to command with no keyboard?

Comment: I am used mini install cd rescue console  to boot it and later plugged usb keybord to ps2 reduction

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I posted a similar question a week ago and got no answer.  But I may have found something.  It seemed to work for me.

I simply unplugged the usb connections and replugged them back.  Activity was reconnected.

I am working through a ps2 KVM with a USB adapter.  I thought the problem might be related to lack of support for my KVM, but no other distributions seem to have this problem.  So I suspect it might have something to do with Unity or one of the programs there timing out.

Anyway, try unplugging and replugging in your PC's usb connectors.  It worked just now for me.

Comment: but strange is they  works out with install cd

Comment: tryed plugging but not solve